# Return 'next' and print message from a tryCatch function to skip to the next loop iteration

Tags: r, loops

I want to use `tryCatch()` to check if packages are installed from within a loop, and then return `next` to break out and skip to the next iteration of the loop if the package failed to load or install. At the same time, I want to return a message to the console reporting this. I can do one, or the other, but I am having trouble figuring out how to do both at the same time. For example, this work:

```
package_list<-c("ggplot2", "grid", "plyr")

for(p in package_list){

  # check if package can't be loaded
  if(!require(p,character.only=TRUE,quietly=TRUE,warn.conflicts=FALSE)){

    write(paste0("Attempting to install package: ",p), stderr())

    # try to install & load the packages, give a message upon failure
    tryCatch(install.packages(p,repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/"),
             warning = function(e){write(paste0("Failed to install pacakge: ", p), stderr())},
             error = function(e){write(paste0("Failed to install pacakge: ", p), stderr())})
    tryCatch(library(p,character.only=TRUE,verbose=FALSE),
             warning = function(e){write(paste0("Failed to install pacakge: ", p), stderr())},
             error = function(e){write(paste0("Failed to install pacakge: ", p), stderr())})

    # try to install & load the packages, skip to next loop iteration upon failure
    tryCatch(install.packages(p,repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/"),warning = next)
    tryCatch(library(p,character.only=TRUE,verbose=FALSE),warning = next)
  }
}
```

But this requires running each command twice; once to fail and return a message about the failure, and then again to fail and skip to the next item in the loop.

Instead, I would much rather perform both actions with a single function, like this:

```
for(p in package_list){
  if(!require(p,character.only=TRUE,quietly=TRUE,warn.conflicts=FALSE)){
    tryCatch(install.packages(p,repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/"),
             warning = function(e){print(paste("Install failed for package: ", p)); return(next)})
    # ...
  }
}
```

However, this fails because you cannot use `next` from within a function:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : no loop for break/next, jumping to top level
```

Is there a way to both return the desired message, and issue the `next` command from within `tryCatch()` in order to perform this function?

Answer (score 1):

Use `message()` rather than `write(..., stderr())`; it takes several arguments that do not have to be `paste()`ed together.

Use `tryCatch()` to return a status code, and act on the status code; the following

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    status <- tryCatch({
        if (i < 5) warning("i < 5")
        if (i > 8) stop("i > 8")
        0L
    }, error=function(e) {
        message(i, ": ", conditionMessage(e))
        1L
    }, warning=function(w) {
        message(i, ": ", conditionMessage(w))
        2L
    })
    if (status != 0L)
        next
    message("success")
}
```

prints

```
1: i < 5
2: i < 5
3: i < 5
4: i < 5
success
success
success
success
9: i > 8
10: i > 8
```